# How do I get a while loop to wait one second, add 1 to an int then display that int in a text block?

Tags: c#, while-loop

What I've got so far:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int intCount = 20;

        while (intCount >= 20 && intCount <30)
        {
            intCount = intCount + 1;
            txtblkCount.Text = intCount.ToString();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }       
    }
```

I need the text box to display each number between 20 and 30 when the button is clicked, however at the moment when I press the button it waits one second then immediately displays 30. I've tried (and failed) at making a timer, putting if statements inside the method, I just can't seem to make this work.

EDIT for X-TECH:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                int intCount = 20;

                while (intCount >= 20 && intCount < 30)
                {
                    intCount = intCount + 1;
                    invoke(new MethodInvoker()) => txtblkCount.Text = intCount.ToString()));
                    txtblkCount.Text = intCount.ToString();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're blocking the UI thread with your current loop.

I'd suggest you download Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-WinForms" or "Rx-WPF") and then do this:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Take(10)
        .Select(n => n + 20)
        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .Subscribe(n => txtblkCount.Text = n.ToString());
}
```

A slightly better version of this code is this:

```
private SerialDisposable _serialDisposable = new SerialDisposable();

private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _serialDisposable.Disposable =
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
            .Take(10)
            .Select(n => n + 20)
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(n => txtblkCount.Text = n.ToString());
}
```

It's better because the `Subscribe(...)` method returns an `IDisposable` that can be used to stop the observable before it naturally completes. The `SerialDisposable` object allows you to re-assign its `.Disposable` property, and, if it is already non `null` it disposes of the current value before assigning the new one. This has the effect of stopping the current observable - which may be important to you if the user is going "click crazy" on the button.

Comment: It's downloading now. Where in my code should I place that?

Comment: @SamBeach - I've updated my answer to show you where to put the code. I also noticed that you're using WPF so I've changed the `ObserveOn(this)` to be `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` to suit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here, is that your code will run through that entire loop without updating the UI inbetween, because your button click event is a synchronous event.  Also, your Sleep is only going for 100 milliseconds, i.e. 1/10 of a second, so you don't notice.  Set that Sleep to 1000, and you'll notice your application will hang up and become unresponsive for 10 seconds before it displays the 30 in the text box.

What you need to do is kick off an asynchronous task from your button click event, and pass that asynchronous task a callback method (i.e. a delegate).  Basically what you want is the click to spawn a new thread, that new thread increments the counter each second, and then calls back to the main UI thread to update the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another thread which check and add integer with 1 and Invoke UI thread to update your text box with that number and obviously sleep worker thread instead of UI

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        int intCount = 20;    
        while (intCount >= 20 && intCount <30)
        {
            intCount = intCount + 1;
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => txtblkCount.Text = intCount.ToString()));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    });
}
```

If you are working in dot net framework < 4.0, then you cannot use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. You have to use

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    int intCount = 20;    
    while (intCount >= 20 && intCount <30)
    {
        intCount = intCount + 1;
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => txtblkCount.Text = intCount.ToString()));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }       
});
thread.Start();
```

Comment: No explanation of your code?  I think the OP would benefit alot more from an explanation than from a code solution with no explanation.

Comment: I tried doing this, but when I got to "Invoke" it started red lining. Also, intellisense didn't recognise MethodInvoker.

Comment: @SamBeach Are you working in simple class? If yes, then you need instance of your form and use `form1.Invoke`.

Comment: @SamBeach Use `Invoke` not `invoke`